# Navigation Links Suddenly Unclickable

Tags: css, html, navigation, hyperlink

I'm working on a page for a class, just to display things (you can see them sorted by chapter in the body) but I originally had a list on the left that I used initially that just listed them all, and I wanted to keep it.

Problem is, once I started adding more CSS - I don't know where exactly - the area on the left just became completely unclickable.  You can't highlight the text, you can't click any of it - nothing.  I have absolutely no idea whatsoever what is causing this.

link to the site [here](http://student.ecc.iwcc.edu/~asmolinski598)

[here](http://pastebin.com/giUisBPb) is a pastebin link showing everything I have.

thank you, i really appreciate any help.

Comment: i can't open the link you provide

Comment: sorry, mixed it up.  fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `.content` div is using `position: absolute;` so  it's taken out of the page flow and overlapping your sidebar because it has no width set (block elements span the full width of your viewport unless you give it a fixed width) ... just add a negative `z-index` value to your `.content` div and it should work fine.

More on [z-index](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/40-how-z-index-works/)

Comment: thank you!  I got it.  I also realized I hadn't updated the css file on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The .content div overlaps entire body area, because of "position: absolute;"

Add `z-index: 9999;` to `#menu` in your CSS and it should be clickable.

Other way is to use "position: relative; float: left;" to both .content and #menu, but you have to be carefull with their widths. Their sum of widths (including padding and margin and border) should be less or equal to the container width. In your case it should be body tag (actually a don't see body tag in your html).